# Onclick gets fired without clicking

Tags: javascript, onclick

`en.onclick = setCookie('english');`

**Why** does this get fired without even clicking on it?

I have 3 flags that should set a cookie to their language when clicked wit the last one always gets fired right away...

Comment: Could you perhaps paste some code?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your code above evaluates `setCookie('english')` and puts its returned value (if any) into `en.onclick`. In order to assign it as an event handler, wrap it into a function:

```
en.onclick = function(){
   setCookie('english');
};
```

Comment: Ok I understand. How can you tell the difference between one to pass somthing to a function (like you do here) Or evaluating it (like i did)

Comment: @Jarco Since you're working with a callback you always need to give a function to be called. Event handlers always expect a callback.

Comment: Probably a novice question: What do you mean by Callback?

Comment: @Jarco: If there are brackets after the function name (with or without parameters), that means you're evaluating it. To pass a function as a function pointer, just use the name of the function. In my above example I created an anonymous inline function and put that function's pointer into en.onclick.

Comment: Ok. Its just a matter of what is possible and what is not with javascript. Thanks. I understand this a lot better now.

Answer (score 5):

cause you must use something like that

```
en.onclick=function(){
  setCookie('english');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you're invoking the method `setCookie(...)`. Try this:

```
en.onclick = setCookie;
```

With the brackets you're invoking the method; without you're handing it as an object.

Or try this:

```
en.onclick = function() { setCookie('english') };
```

Here we create a new function which calls `setCookie` with the appropriate argument.

Answer (score 2):

Well that's because you're running the method and assigning the result to en.onclick.

What you probably want to do us

```
en.onclick = function(){setCookie('english');};
```