# Image error event not having desired effect

Tags: javascript

I've had an issue for two days and i'm at breaking point. I would like to change the image `src` of an image when the image fails to load (image doesn't exist).

In the following example the first two images do exist but yet all of the image `src` are replaced by the error event.

https://jsfiddle.net/zq5tsbmj/

```
var errorHandler = function(imageParsed) {
  imageParsed.src = "http://www.theemailcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/no-image-placeholder-big-300x200.jpg";
};

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img"),
  len = imgs.length;

for (var i = 0, lenImage = len; i < lenImage; i++) {
  imgs[i].onerror = errorHandler(imgs[i]);
}
```

I thought this was because the event was running too quickly. So as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743863/onclick-gets-fired-without-clicking) I assigned it in an event manner

https://jsfiddle.net/zq5tsbmj/1/

```
var errorHandler = function(imageParsed) {
  imageParsed.src = "http://www.theemailcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/no-image-placeholder-big-300x200.jpg";
  alert('error');
};

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img"),
  len = imgs.length;

for (var i = 0, lenImage = len; i < lenImage; i++) {
  imgs[i].onerror = function() {
    errorHandler(imgs[i]);
  };
}
```

But this doesn't trigger the error function ever, even though the last image should fail.

---

Could someone please explain to me what exactly i'm doing wrong. Please don't just provide links to other questions. I would really like to know in simple terms why this code isn't working exactly as expected and what the solution is, otherwise I fear I won't learn from it. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Comment: @Rafalon I need to use the exact code in my example. I cannot use inline code as per your suggestion. This isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Then maybe this one with `$().on("error", function(){});` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984287/how-to-show-alternate-image-if-source-image-is-not-found-onerror-working-in-ie

Comment: @Rafalon thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't work either https://jsfiddle.net/zq5tsbmj/10/

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in both cases

**Case 1**

Your for-loop should be assigning the function rather than return value of the function, make it

```
for (var i = 0, lenImage = len; i < lenImage; i++) {
  imgs[i].onerror = errorHandler;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zq5tsbmj/3/)

**Case 2**

`Onerror` is invoked asynchronously so, value of `i` must be locked before passing the same to function

```
for (var i = 0, lenImage = len; i < lenImage; i++) {
  imgs[i].onerror = function( i ) {
    errorHandler(imgs[i]);
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks, i was really hoping this would work. do you have a working example? I tried it and it doesn't display the error image https://jsfiddle.net/zq5tsbmj/4/

Comment: The last image isn't appearing for me? Google Chrome.

Comment: @steve last image is a valid url? it didn't invoked onerror event.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise example.com would still resolve with a dummy image. If I use a url where the image doesn't exist, it still doesn't invoke the error https://jsfiddle.net/zq5tsbmj/22/

Comment: @steve Problem is you need to bind `onerror` event at the same time when you are attaching the `src` attribute.. try this https://jsfiddle.net/zq5tsbmj/24/

Answer (score 0):

In the first case `https://jsfiddle.net/zq5tsbmj/` here when we load the page itself, below code is getting executed,

```
for (var i = 0, lenImage = len; i < lenImage; i++) {
  imgs[i].onerror = errorHandler(imgs[i]);
}
```

At this point, `errorHandler` function is getting executed and all the images get replaced.

In the second case `https://jsfiddle.net/zq5tsbmj/1/` here when we load the page itself, below code is getting executed,

```
for (var i = 0, lenImage = len; i < lenImage; i++) {
  imgs[i].onerror = function() {
  errorHandler(imgs[i]);
 };
}
```

here we are just binding the event against the images but it wont get executed.

To make it work, in all the `Image` tag add a event called `onerror="errorHandler(this)"`

```
<img src="http://artandcraftdays.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/buterfly_and_drops-263x300.png" width="100" onerror="errorHandler(this)"/>
<img src="https://www.chromacolour.co.uk/media/catalog/category/art-supplies_5.jpg" width="100" onerror="errorHandler(this)"/>
<img src="https://www.exagggggmple.com/media/doesnt-exists.jpg" width="100"  onerror="errorHandler(this)"/>
```

and have only one `function` below and remove the other scripts.

```
var errorHandler = function(imageParsed) {
  imageParsed.src = "http://www.theemailcompany.com/wp-
content/uploads/2016/02/no-image-placeholder-big-300x200.jpg";
  alert('error');
};
```

And this will work as you expect.